# In Signalr .net core - where should validation take place?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

If I have a hub method that accepts parameters

e.g.

```
public IObservable<MyStreamItem> StreamData(SomeRequestData request)
{}
```

How do I propogate validation errors in the request?

An actual http request is only made when the socket connection is established.
So subsequent calls to Hub methods dont pass through any middleware. They are just frames/messages in the open websocket.

I've had a look at this package which is for the previous version of Signalr (for the full .net framework)
https://github.com/AGiorgetti/SignalR.Validation

This uses a `HubPipelineModule` which doesn't seem to exist in the new .net core Signalr.

Is there an appropriate place in the pipeline that I can tap into to do the validation?
Or should it be done in the hub method itself? And if so, how would you conditionally return a structured set of errors, as opposed to what the actual return type is meant to be?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently no HubPipelineModules in SignalR alpha but we're looking at an equivalent for preview 2. Today, you'd need to do it in the method and potentially throw an error to get it back to the client.

Comment: thanks  @davidfowl - when do you expect preview 2 to drop ?

Comment: hi @davidfowl , did this make it into the RC? If so, what is the feature called. I don't see anything likely in the source code

Comment: There are no hub pipeline modules in ASP.NET Core SignalR.